# Moving object from a stack to an array C++

Tags: c++

Hey guys so I am writing some coursework and I am almost there, in my code I create a treasure chest and a bag for the player. When the Player is shown the  items in the chest they are asked to keep the items which are then stored in there bag or discard the items.

While testing my code I have noticed that the item the player is being shown is not the one that then stores in the bag, almost like the bag is taking from an invisible stack. Then at the end when I call the players bag it still shows as empty as if no items where ever stored????

Please can someone tell me where I am going wrong and how I might resolve it???

These are the specific sections of code that is causing the bug:

```
    void PrintTreasureChest()
{
    //TreasureChest A;
    int j;
    for (j = 1; j < 5; j++)
    {
        cout << "Item " << j << " in your chest is: " << endl;
        cout << "Name:" << (TreasureChest().Chest.top()).Name << endl;
        cout << "Rarity out of 3: " << (TreasureChest().Chest.top()).Rarity << endl;
        cout << "Part of a set: " << (TreasureChest().Chest.top()).Set << endl;
        cout << " " << endl;
        PlayerChoice(A);
        TreasureChest().Chest.pop();
        cout << " " << endl;
    }
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "This chest is now empty" << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "Items in bag: " << endl;
    //Game().ShowRucksack();
    return;

}

void PlayerChoice()
{
    char Answer;
    cout << "If you want to keep the item press Y" << endl;
    cout << "If you want to discard the item press N" << endl;
    cin >> Answer;
    while (Answer == 'Y' || Answer == 'y')
    {
        cout << "Item stored in your bag" << endl;
        StoreItem();
        return;
    }
    while (Answer == 'N' || Answer == 'n')
    {
        cout << "Item was discared from the Treasure Chest" << endl;
        return;
    }
    while (Answer != 'y' || Answer != 'Y' || Answer != 'N' || Answer != 'n')
    {
        cout << "To decide press Y for accept OR press N for Decline" << endl;
        cin >> Answer;
        if (Answer == 'Y' || Answer == 'y') {
            cout << "Item stored in your bag" << endl;

            //store item in bag
            return;
        }
        else (Answer == 'N' || Answer == 'n'); {
            cout << "Item was discared from the Treasure Chest" << endl;
            return;
        }
        return;
    }
}

void StoreItem()
{
    int dim = 10;
    int P = index(Rucksack, dim);
    Rucksack[P] = A.Chest.top();
    cout << "Item placed in your Bag: " << Rucksack[P].Name << endl;
    return;
}
```

Here is the whole code:

```
// Loot Class v11.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
```

//

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#define LootNumber 14
using namespace std;

// the 3 arrays initialise the 3 stats of each item
string NameOption[] = { "Stone", "Leather Gloves", "Dragon Gauntlets", "Chair Leg", "Dragon Scale Helmet", "Pebble", "Rusted Breastplate", "Dragon Breastplate", "Empty Bottle", "Chainmail Trousers", "Dragon Skin Trousers", "Broken Stick", "Dagger", "Dragons Sword" };
int RarityOption[] = { 0, 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 };
bool SetOption[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 };

// this class is grouping Name, Rarity and Set. Resulting in every Loot object made, contains 3 variables
class Loot
{
public:
    string Name;
    int Rarity;
    bool Set;

    // constructor initialises each of the feilds
    Loot(string N, int R, bool S)
    {
        Name = N;
        Rarity = R;
        Set = S;

    }
    // default constructor
    Loot()
    {
        Name = "Empty";
        Rarity = 0;
        Set = false;
    }
    // Prints a randomly selected item of loot to the screen, used to check randomisation and that all loot variables print in the correct order
    void PrintLoot()
    {
        int i = rand() % LootNumber;
        Loot A(NameOption[i], RarityOption[i], SetOption[i]);
        cout << "Loot item: " << A.Name << endl;
        cout << "Rarity out of 3: " << A.Rarity << endl;
        cout << "Part of set: " << A.Set << endl;
    }

};
// enables the creation of a container to stack  Loot items in
class TreasureChest
{
public:
    stack<Loot> Chest;

    // stacks 4 random items in the chest
    TreasureChest()
    {
        int i = rand() % LootNumber;
        int j = rand() % LootNumber;
        int k = rand() % LootNumber;
        int h = rand() % LootNumber;

        Chest.push(Loot(NameOption[j], RarityOption[j], SetOption[j]));
        Chest.push(Loot(NameOption[k], RarityOption[k], SetOption[k]));
        Chest.push(Loot(NameOption[i], RarityOption[i], SetOption[i]));
        Chest.push(Loot(NameOption[h], RarityOption[h], SetOption[h]));
    }

    // prints full contents of Treasure Chest to screen
    void ShowFullChest()
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cout << "Item: " << i << endl;
            cout << "Name:" << TreasureChest().Chest.top().Name << endl;
            cout << "Rarity out of 3: " << TreasureChest().Chest.top().Rarity << endl;
            cout << "Part of a set: " << TreasureChest().Chest.top().Set << endl;
            TreasureChest().Chest.pop();
        }
    }

};

// Creates container for player to store their chosen Loot items
class PlayerRuckSack
{
public:
    Loot Rucksack[10];

    // default constructor initialising each array 
        PlayerRuckSack()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Rucksack[i] = { "Empty", 0, false };
        }
    };

    // prints contents of a rucksack to the screen to allow the player to see what they have collected
    void ShowRucksack()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            cout << Rucksack[i].Name << " " << Rucksack[i].Set << " " << Rucksack[i].Rarity << " " << endl;
        }
    }

    // replaces an each array with items of Loot and prints when all arrays have been replaced
    int index(Loot x[], int n)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int index;
        while (x[i].Name != "empty" && 0 && false && i < n)
        {
            i++;
            index = i;
            return index;
        }
        while (i == n)
        {
            cout << "BAG FULL" << endl;
        }
    }

};

// For runing the game
class Game : public PlayerRuckSack
{
public:
    string PlayerName;
    TreasureChest A;


    Game()
    {
        PlayerName = "User 1";
    }

    Game(string U)
    {
        PlayerName = U;
    }
    // intro message to start game
    void StartGame()
    {
        cout << "Welcome to the Cave of Luck" << endl;
        cout << "What is your name brave warrior" << endl;
        cin >> PlayerName;
        cout << PlayerName << " There are 3 Treasure Chests in this cave" << endl;
        cout << "Treasure Chests contain many different items" << endl;
        cout << "However it appears your bag is small and can only hold 10 items in total" << endl;
        cout << "Choose wisley " << PlayerName << endl;
        cout << "Good Luck!!" << endl;
        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << " " << endl;
    }

    //Gives player choise whether to keep or discard each loot item 
    void PlayerChoice()
    {
        char Answer;
        cout << "If you want to keep the item press Y" << endl;
        cout << "If you want to discard the item press N" << endl;
        cin >> Answer;
        while (Answer == 'Y' || Answer == 'y')
        {
            cout << "Item stored in your bag" << endl;
            StoreItem();
            return;
        }
        while (Answer == 'N' || Answer == 'n')
        {
            cout << "Item was discared from the Treasure Chest" << endl;
            return;
        }
        while (Answer != 'y' || Answer != 'Y' || Answer != 'N' || Answer != 'n')
        {
            cout << "To decide press Y for accept OR press N for Decline" << endl;
            cin >> Answer;
            if (Answer == 'Y' || Answer == 'y') {
                cout << "Item stored in your bag" << endl;

                //store item in bag
                return;
            }
            else (Answer == 'N' || Answer == 'n'); {
                cout << "Item was discared from the Treasure Chest" << endl;
                return;
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    // Prints the top of TreasureChest to the screen plus uses Playerchoise() after each item is shown
    void PrintTreasureChest()
    {
        //TreasureChest A;
        int j;
        for (j = 1; j < 5; j++)
        {
            cout << "Item " << j << " in your chest is: " << endl;
            cout << "Name:" << (TreasureChest().Chest.top()).Name << endl;
            cout << "Rarity out of 3: " << (TreasureChest().Chest.top()).Rarity << endl;
            cout << "Part of a set: " << (TreasureChest().Chest.top()).Set << endl;
            cout << " " << endl;
            PlayerChoice(A);
            TreasureChest().Chest.pop();
            cout << " " << endl;
        }
        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << "This chest is now empty" << endl;
        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << "Items in bag: " << endl;
        //Game().ShowRucksack();
        return;

    }
    // informs player another chest is coming 
    void NextChest()
    {
        cout << "Your next chest contains: " << endl;
        cout << " " << endl;
    }
    // Prints end Game message
    void EndGame()
    {
        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << "You have opened all the Chests, come back soon to the Cave of Treasures" << endl;
        cout << " THANKYOU FOR PLAYING" << endl;
    }

    void StoreItem()
    {
        int dim = 10;
        int P = index(Rucksack, dim);
        Rucksack[P] = A.Chest.top();
        cout << "Item placed in your Bag: " << Rucksack[P].Name << endl; //B.Rucksack[P].Set << B.Rucksack[P].Rarity << endl;
        return;
    }
};




int main()
{
    Game A;
    //TreasureChest A;
    PlayerRuckSack B;
    //A.StartGame();
    srand(time(NULL));
    A.PrintTreasureChest();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << B.Rucksack[i].Name << " " << B.Rucksack[i].Set << " " << B.Rucksack[i].Rarity << " " << endl;
    }
    //A.NextChest();
    A.EndGame();

    //TreasureChest A;
    //PlayerRuckSack B;
    //int dim = 10;
    //int P = index(B.Rucksack, dim);
    //B.Rucksack[P] = A.Chest.top();
    //cout << "Item in your Bag " << B.Rucksack[P].Name <<  B.Rucksack[P].Set << B.Rucksack[P].Rarity << endl;

    //cout << P << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: I use visual studios which has a built in debug. However I do not have time to learn to use a debugger as this work is due in on the 5th of may :S.
I will learn that for my next piece, this is the first ever piece i have written only started in December so i am very low on knowledge

Comment: That's plenty of time.  It only takes about 30 minutes to get acquainted with the debugger.  That leaves you 3 days.

Comment: You have heard of pen and paper, with which you can trace the program's logic and find out where you made a mistake. Your deadline does not change that, sorry. You should have started earlier. This shall be a valuable learning experience. :)

Comment: Been working on this for months I'm not a programmer, just wanted some advise on the bug. I'm sure you started somewhere too

Comment: F10 would have moved a highlight over the first executable line of your program.  All you had to do was keep hitting it over and over again to see what the debugger did, i.e. move the highlight to the next line that is executed, and just kept your eyes on that window showing the variables changing.  It was that easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know why nothing is stored in your `Rucksack`

```
int index(Loot x[], int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    int index;
    while (x[i].Name != "empty" && 0 && false && i < n)
    {
        i++;
        index = i;
        return index;
    }
    while (i == n)
    {
        cout << "BAG FULL" << endl;
    }
}
```

Take a careful look at this line:

```
while (x[i].Name != "empty" && 0 && false && i < n)
```

`&& 0 && false`? Both `0` and `false` mean this is always false and the Rucksack will be reported as empty no matter what.

Then the code will fall out the bottom of `index()` without returning a value.
After that program behaviour is undefined because you use a return value that was not returned. Any craziness might come after that.

Fix that and come back with another question if you can't figure out your other problem.
It is currently a bit vague.

Comment: Thank you that gives me somewhere to start, really appreciate the advise

Comment: Im trying to now replace a specific part of the array
My problem is its not replacing the word
I made a simple version testing with:

    int spindex(string x[], int n)
{
 int i = 0;
 int tindex;

 while (x[i] != "empty" && i < n)
 {

  tindex = i;
  i++;

 }
 return tindex;
}


int main()
{
 string Bob[] = { "shaun", "empty", "tom", "empty", "chris", "sharon", "empty" };
 int pim = 10;
 int Q = spindex(Bob, pim);
 Bob[Q] = "BOB";
 cout << Q << endl;
 cout << Bob[Q] << endl;
 for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
 {
  cout << Bob[i] << endl;
 }

 return 0;
}

Comment: @Chronic. Reduce that to a MCVE and post a new question. That is unreadable unformatted in a comment.